# Create WinForms ComboBox with non-selectable items

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, combobox

How to create combobox control with non-selectable items? For example, such groupnames or categorynames which visually divide items in dropdownlist into some groups or categories.

Comment: You may give a bit more detail.  Is this WPF, Windows Forms or some other UI framework?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Instead of adding strings to your combobox you could add a special class and use selected item to determine whether the item is selected or not.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private class ComboBoxItem
    {
        public int Value { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public bool Selectable { get; set; }
    }

    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        this.comboBox1.ValueMember = "Value";
        this.comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Text";
        this.comboBox1.Items.AddRange(new[] {
            new ComboBoxItem() { Selectable = false, Text="Unselectable", Value=0},
            new ComboBoxItem() { Selectable = true, Text="Selectable1", Value=1},
            new ComboBoxItem() { Selectable = true, Text="Selectable2", Value=2},
            new ComboBoxItem() { Selectable = false, Text="Unselectable", Value=3},
            new ComboBoxItem() { Selectable = true, Text="Selectable3", Value=4},
            new ComboBoxItem() { Selectable = true, Text="Selectable4", Value=5},
        });

        this.comboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += (cbSender, cbe) => {
            var cb = cbSender as ComboBox;

            if (cb.SelectedItem != null && cb.SelectedItem is ComboBoxItem && ((ComboBoxItem) cb.SelectedItem).Selectable == false) {
                // deselect item
                cb.SelectedIndex = -1;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: This was my first thought as well. However you can still type the item text into the ComboBox and thereby selecting the unselectable item.

Comment: No. In my case I use DropDownList style for ComboBox disabling texteditor.

Comment: Your code is very well and it help for me. But another question - how to disable not only selecting items in list but disable tracking non-selectable items by mouse.

Comment: IMHO, this is difficult to achieve without drawing the drop down box on your own.

Comment: This is a nice solution, but an extra wish in case of non selectable item would be to come back to the previously selected item instead of removing any selection.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here on [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/combobox/ReadOnlyComboBoxByClaudio.aspx) for a readonly Combo Box, here's another article to make the [readonly](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/combobox/disabledcombodisplay.aspx) combo box 'decent' looking... Here's another that shows how to override the basic standard combo box to make it [readonly](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/combobox/ReadOnlyCB.aspx) as Sani suggested.