# Is it possible to disable an item in a dropdownlist combobox in c#?

Tags: c#, combobox, drop-down-menu

Can I disable an item in a dropdownlist in c#?

For example, I have 2 dropdownlist combobox. Both of them consist of months (jan, feb, mar, apr, etc....) and both of them will function like a range of month in a certain year.
When I choose apr on the 1st combobox, the second combobox can't choose jan, feb, mar

Comment: How is order? Are indexes same?

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can.

`ListItem`s in your dropdownlist have an [Enabled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitem.enabled.aspx) property. You can set this to `false` to disable them.

EDIT:

Sorry I made the assumption you were using WebForms (ASP.Net). For windows forms, you can take a look at this answer: [Create WinForms ComboBox with non-selectable items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2290563/create-winforms-combobox-with-non-selectable-items)  - its the same principle but with some slight implementation details because Combobox `Items` collection is one of objects. `Dropdownlist` (the Web form equivalent) uses typed 'ListItem' objects.

HTH.

Comment: how can i add a listitem? combobox.items.add()?

Comment: @Joseph: Use YourCombobox.Items.Add(object) or .AddRange(object[]).

Comment: @5arx: tnx for the help dude. @Jason Down: ok ill try that