# Windows Form - How add header not selectable in combobox item in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I need create a custom combobox control that allows header as separator which should not be selectable using the mouse move or key press.

this is example:

```
Header1
  item1
  item2
  item3
Header2
  item4
  item5
```

I tried many solutions, without success. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try looking here: [Create WinForms ComboBox with non-selectable items](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2290563/create-winforms-combobox-with-non-selectable-items)

Comment: I tryed this code, not return as I require.. works in different ways

Comment: @sparky68967 that solution is really crappy.

Comment: @vincenzolopalo winforms doesn't support customization. You can achieve this in WPF with some 5 to 10 lines of XAML and no code at all.

Comment: thanks for info HighCore, than I need pass to WPF

Comment: @HighCore I wasn't vouching for the solution one way or the other. I was merely providing an option to look at. And saying WinForms doesn't support customization is like saying cars can't be customized either. Sure, you can buy an upgraded one from a dealer right off the bat, but there is nothing stopping you from adding your own customizations with a little effort.

Comment: @sparky68687 `with a little effort`, sorry but my opinion is that a framework `supports` a specific thing, if this thing can be achieved using that framework without having to spend an entire day doing HACKS to achieve what you want. I would like you to post your winforms-based solution for the different appearance between items inside a combobox, say the "Header" ones with bold, and the "Item" ones with a margin like the OP asked for.

Comment: a simple google search might lead you to the correct solution try with this link http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/da-DK/winforms/thread/2962b0c9-d365-4645-a271-922fe6b2516c and even better example [stackoverflow previous post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2290563/create-winforms-combobox-with-non-selectable-items)

Comment: I try those links before to start this question without found solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Once again, WPF can easily provide solutions that would require tons of horrible hacks in winforms.

Copy and paste my code in a File -> New Project -> WPF Application in Visual Studio.

You will quickly notice that my solution not only provides a different visual appearance for Header Items, but it also prevents unwanted selection, be it via mouse or keyboard, and it doesn't need to subclass the regular ComboBox class, which would lead to lesser maintainability.

[image: ComboBox]

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication5.Window2"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication5"
        Title="Window2" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding}" DisplayMemberPath="DisplayText"
                  VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                  Height="25" Width="100">
            <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsHeader}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsHeader}" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10,0,0,0"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ComboBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code Behind:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApplication5
{
    public partial class Window2 : Window
    {
        public Window2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var list = new List<ComboBoxItem>
                {
                    new ComboBoxItem {DisplayText = "Header1", IsHeader = true},
                    new ComboBoxItem {DisplayText = "Item1", IsHeader = false},
                    new ComboBoxItem {DisplayText = "Item2", IsHeader = false},
                    new ComboBoxItem {DisplayText = "Item3", IsHeader = false},
                    new ComboBoxItem {DisplayText = "Header2", IsHeader = true},
                    new ComboBoxItem {DisplayText = "Item4", IsHeader = false},
                    new ComboBoxItem {DisplayText = "Item5", IsHeader = false},
                    new ComboBoxItem {DisplayText = "Item6", IsHeader = false},
                };

            DataContext = list;
        }
    }

    public class ComboBoxItem
    {
        public string DisplayText { get; set; }
        public bool IsHeader { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 HighCore nice answer but you are assuming the OP knows `XAML and WPF`

Comment: @hanspassant my integration argument still stands, my solution can be placed in an `ElementHost` in winforms.

Comment: it would be useful a solution for winforms. :(

Comment: @vincenzolopalo it would be useful if winforms actually supported everything WPF supports. Unfortunately it doesn't, that's why you should immediately think of trashing it altogether and use a newer, more scalable, more performant, more efficient framework.

Comment: @vincenzolopalo still, if you want to hurt yourself using winforms, you can give a try to the [`ElementHost`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.elementhost.aspx), which can be used to host WPF content in a winforms application, then you could put the ComboBox in my example inside the ElementHost.

Comment: This was a great help! FYI, for future WPF noobs like me, there is a point of confusion in the code example. The ComboBoxItem class that is defined in the code has the same name as the ComboBoxItem that is referenced in the XAML as the TargetType. So when adapting the example to your code, do not use your class name as the TargetType as I did; that actually needs to be ComboBoxItem.

Answer (score 3):

Try this custom combo box. It ignores the header, but the header is drawn exactly like any other item and when you select a subitem, it will contain those extra spaces. But hopefully this leads you in the right direction.

```
public class CustomComboBox : ComboBox
{
    int currentlySelectedIndex = -1;

    protected override void OnSelectionChangeCommitted(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.SelectedIndex != -1)
        {
            // Check if we shouldn ignore it:
            object currentlySelectedItem = this.Items[this.SelectedIndex];

            if (ShouldIgnore(currentlySelectedItem))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Ignoring it! Resetting the index.");

                this.SelectedIndex = currentlySelectedIndex;
            }
        }

        base.OnSelectionChangeCommitted(e);
    }

    protected virtual bool ShouldIgnore(object selectedItem)
    {
        // This is a category if it starts with a space. 
        return !selectedItem.ToString().StartsWith(" ");     
    }

    protected override void OnDropDown(EventArgs e)
    {
        // Save the current index when the drop down shows:
        currentlySelectedIndex = this.SelectedIndex;

        base.OnDropDown(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your solution is a hack. and doesn't provide the visual difference for the headers the OP is asking for.

Comment: He's not very clear on that he wants any visual difference except for the spaces. Thanks for being friendly though.

Your answer however sidesteps the question altogether and you provide a solution in a totally different framework! Why not give an answer using Qt?

Comment: because QT doesn't actually replace winforms. WPF does. period.

Comment: Your answer is highly opinionated. Of course I agree that it may be preferable to use WPF but that's not answering the question.

Comment: I'm still waiting the winforms version of my code, with Bolds and Margins.

Comment: Also, I don't know what is the level of interoperability between winforms and QT, but WPF can easily be integrated in an existing winforms application via the `ElementHost`, therefore whenever you need anything but the default battleship-gray windows 98 style winforms controls, you can place an ElementHost and WPF content inside of it.

Comment: My Qt remark was ironic, since it is a clear practice on SO to answer the question itself, not with a different framework which the programmer may know *nothing* about.

The margins are there with the spaces in the text. He was being very unclear if he wanted the categories formatted in bold, although I admit that he hinted for it in the example.

If he needs the formatting I would certainly recommend that he would rather use WPF or some 3rd party control library (rather than custom painting the control). But still, that's not answering *his* question, which is cleary tagged with winforms.

Comment: I would gadly provide an answer in winforms if it was actually possible without a whole bunch of hacks (such as adding trailing spaces to string values), my integration argument still stands, my solution can be placed in an ElementHost in winforms.