# How to disable items based on condition in combo box?

Tags: c#, combobox, windows

Am developing a windows application in C#.

The user has to select some listed values in combo box. Those values will be added to Database. When the same user login and select the combo box, already selected values should be visible but shouldn't be get selected....

I referred various websites. All stating to change the colour of Existing values....But it is not enough. I need to disable the values... Is there any options to do it.

Note : Am populating the combo-box items from a database table.

Comment: Well can you not filter out the items and not show them at all ?

Comment: No @V4Vendetta, I need to display all those items. But to disable the existing items....

Comment: What should happen when a user selects an existing value?

Comment: for such scenario why you are using combobox, two Listbox and two buttons with ">" "<" text on it would be better option

Comment: could explain a bit more why you need to display them if the user can't select them? I mean I know there are some context... but maybe in your case a combobox isn't the good option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set `ComboBox.SelectedIndex = -1` for your desired value;

The code is not tested but something like this will help you

```
if (combobox.selectedIndex == (Index of your value))
{
    combobox.selectedIndex = -1;
}
```

In this way if you try to choose that item it will set selected index to -1 and you will not able to choose that item.

Comment: Its working... But I need some thing to be get disabling (i.e) even the user cand select the existing items.

Answer (score 0):

The following link might be helpful for you

[Create WinForms ComboBox with non-selectable items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2290563/create-winforms-combobox-with-non-selectable-items)

While biding values from db set the selectable property true or false and in the selectedindexchanged event set the selectedindex of the item to -1.

Don't forget to mark it as answer if it is helpful for you.

**Note: Before doing this make sure that it is required to show the items. If it is not required just filter them and bind the remaining values.**