# C# how to make it so that a combobox doesn't highlight the text when selecting an item

Tags: c#, drop-down-menu, combobox

I'm using a ComboBox with DropDownList property enabled in Microsoft Visual Studio. The drop down box works just fine, however when I open the form it has the text highlighted as though you do a Ctrl A on it. I would prefer it such that it didn't appear highlighted.

EDIT:

It would appear however that the cause of the problem is that my co-worker didn't instantiate the comboBox as a Drop down box as I thought he had. So in able to do that I changed the code to

`stateComboBox.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;`

This has the desired effect. Thanks to all who had suggestions.

Comment: I found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2290563/create-winforms-combobox-with-non-selectable-items but this is abit more in-depth then what I was hoping for. If that's what I end up having to do then I'll get it to work but I was wondering if there was something more simple that may work.

Comment: You just want to avoid it when the form starts?

Comment: Winform? WPF? or ASP.net?.

Comment: Do you not want it selected, or do you just want the selection color to be the same as the non-selection color?

Comment: @RandyP. that's a **different thing**. You didn't say your combobox allows user to enter something or not. `DropDownList` will make your combobox `ReadOnly`.

Comment: The difference between DropDown and DropDownList is DropDown allows text input.  So just mind that this also changes.

Comment: That's correct, I was aware of that. I wanted it to be a simple drop down list. It wasn't supposed to have the ability to enter text, again, I thought it was set that way however when I started digging into the code I noticed it was never there. Thus why I wasn't sure at first why it was highlighting the text since it shouldn't of been writable.

Answer (score 0):

How about clearing the selection when the form is activated:

```
private void Form1_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    comboBox1.Select(0, 0);
}
```

Of course it's likely only because this is the default form input that it gets focused and highlighted to begin with. (TabIndex is set to 0 on this control)