# restrict users from selecting value on previous index in Combobox c# winform

Tags: c#, winforms, enums, combobox

I have a Combobox in winform. It is binded to an enum. The enum displays the status of article in an order. I want user to follow the order and restrict users from selecting previous status if updated. I have tried selectedIndexchanged event but it didnt work.

```
public enum Articlestatus : Byte
    {
        Inplagiarism = 0,
        Consentletter = 1,
        Inreview = 2,
        AuthorRevision = 4,
        ReReview = 8,
        Reject = 16,
        Accept = 32,
        Published = 64
    }
```

Comment: Yes some some details will help.

Comment: You need to show *what* didnt work if you want help fixing it.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create WinForms ComboBox with non-selectable items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2290563/create-winforms-combobox-with-non-selectable-items)

Comment: How do you determine when a status is "selected". Do you mean the moment they choose one value, all previous values should be removed (or not allowed to be selected)?

Comment: @RufusL not removed. they shld not be allowed to select previous valus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it would be to track the previously selected item in a variable, and then, in the `SelectedIndexChanged` event, re-select the previous item ir if the user tries to select something less:

```
// Keep track of currently selected index
private int lastSelectedIndex = 0;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    comboBox1.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Articlestatus));
    comboBox1.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;

    // Select first item and update our tracking variable
    comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
    lastSelectedIndex = comboBox1.SelectedIndex;
}

private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Do nothing if they re-selected the same item
    if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == lastSelectedIndex) return;

    // If the newly selected item is less than the previous one, reset to previous one
    if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex < lastSelectedIndex)
    {
        comboBox1.SelectedIndex = lastSelectedIndex;
    }
    else
    {
        lastSelectedIndex = comboBox1.SelectedIndex;
    }
}
```

Note that this code is not very flexile for the user. If they accidentally choose the wrong item, they're stuck. I imagine that the code to update the `lastSelectedIndex` should go somewhere else, like in some "TaskCompleted" event that, when fired, signifies they've done something that commits them to the selection.

Comment: thats the problem. Basically, i am coping values from gridview on cellclick event and some articles has previous values by default. Otherwise, it works.